# How to define the reference between 2d-array and 1d pointer, and fix SSE2 incompatibility?

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

I'm trying to step in using SIMD instructions. I wrote very simple code lines but it is always saying

```
char test[16];
__m128i *X,*Y,*C;
X =(__m128i*) test;
Y =(__m128i*) test;
C = __mm_add_epi8(X,Y);
```

note: expected '__m128i' but argument is of type '__vector(2) long long int*'

Edit:
the previous procedure was wrong due to assigning 2D-array to 1D pointer of the same size. I might having problem understanding the 2D array address and dereferencing.

here is how the 2D-array is defined in my code.

```
unsigned char **img = malloc(16* sizeof(int *));
for (i=0;i<16;i++) {
         img[i] = malloc(16* sizeof(int *));
}
```

I need now to copy 1 row of the 2D array to another pointer for the same width. 
either this

```
unsigned char test[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

or this

```
unsigned char *test = malloc(16 * sizeof(unsigned char *));
```

As I understood the next three lines they most give the same address, as the first and second line print the address of the first row in the 2D array and the third print the address of the first item in the first row which it is the same.

```
printf("%d\n", img); 
printf("%d\n", img[0]);
printf("%d\n", &img[0][0]);
```

if I'm using 16 unsigned char that means the next row must start after 16bit address but by printing (img+1), img[1] or img[1][0] it appears that the address start after 72bit, which I can't understand why. 
thought I wanted to copy the address of each row to another pointer and use it as single array I used.

```
test = img[0]; 
test = img[1];
.
.
test = img[15];
```

it allows me to access each field by using test[i];using the next coming code it works fine with test[0].

```
 X = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)test);
```

but I got segmentation fault with test[i] when i is bigger than 0. knowing that if I copy the row item by item using for loop below it works. any suggestion why ?

```
for(i=0; i<16; i++)
{ 
    test[i] = img[1][i];
} 
X = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 issues with this code:

- Error is in the last line `C = ...`. `_mm_add_epi8` doesn't accept `__m128i*`. Please try `*C = _mm_add_epi8(*X, *Y)`
- There is only one `_` in the intrinsic name.
- `C` pointer was not initialized and you might get Segmentation Violation. Initialize `C` or don't use pointers.

Comment: I have segmentation fault with this      
 base = (unsigned char *)img[0]; 
 X = (__m128i *) base;
 test = (unsigned char *)img[1];
 Y = (__m128i *) test;
 *X= _mm_add_epi8(X[0],Y[1]);

Comment: @Feras: you want `ptr=img`, not `ptr=img[0]`.  You need the address, not the value, of the first byte.

Comment: @PeterCordes img is 2D-array. so I was thinking to get the first row address by assigning img[0];